Sum of two non-adjacent vectors in a quadrilateral
If I have a closed, convex quadrilateral formed by 3D vectors $\vec{k_1}$, $\vec{k_2}$, $\vec{k_3}$, $\vec{k_4}$, where $\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_2}+\vec{k_3}+\vec{k_4}=0$ and I know the magnitudes $|\vec{k_1}|=k_1$, $|\vec{k_2}|=k_2$, $|\vec{k_3}|=k_3$, $|\vec{k_4}|=k_4$. What is the most straightforward way to determine the magnitude of the sum of two non-adjacent vectors, e.g. $|\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_3}|$ in terms of the diagonal $\vec{D}$, the angle $\psi$ and the vectors magnitudes?

Moreover, given a set of possible magnitudes $(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4)$, e.g., (2,4,6,8), is it true that only 3 configurations are allowed? -- Note that the quadrilateral is not on a plane but in 3D, this is only a simplification of the possible quadrilateral configurations for any $\psi$.

Context: I am a physicist working with 4-point functions in Fourier space. Terms such as $|\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_3}|$ appear in my calculations and I didn't manage to get it.
EDIT: I might have found a partial solution. Please let me know if this is correct.

First, let us move $\vec{k_3}$ to the end of $\vec{k_1}$ to visualize $\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_3}$ (in green). I tilted a bit $\vec{k_3}$ but just for visualization issues.



Now let us suppose, for now, that $\psi=\pi$, such that the quadrilateral is planar. We can first determine $\alpha$ (in pink) and $\gamma$ (in grey) by cosine rule:

$$
\alpha = \arccos\left(\frac{k_4^2-k_3^2-D^2}{2k_3 D}\right) \\
\gamma = \arccos\left(\frac{k_2^2-k_1^2-D^2}{2k_1 D}\right)
$$


Using the parallel lines theorem, we can identify $\theta=\alpha-\gamma$ (in yellow).

Using cosine rule again, we obtain:


$$
|\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_3}| = \sqrt { k_1^2 + k_3^2 + 2 k_1 k_3 \cos{\theta} }
$$

Now let us consider $\psi \neq \pi$, such that the quadrilateral is not planar anymore. In this case, we have

$$
\vec{k_1}=(k_1\sin\gamma,0,k_1\cos\gamma) \\ 
\vec{k_3}=(k_3\sin\alpha\cos\psi,k_3\sin\alpha\sin\psi,k_3\cos\alpha)
$$
Such that we have:
$$
|\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_3}|^2=k_1^2 + k_3^2 + 2 k_1 k_3 (\sin\alpha\sin\gamma\cos\psi+\cos\alpha\cos\gamma)
$$
Note that we recover the planar case for $\psi=\pi$.

The configurations in the second figure just point out that opposite of side of length $8$ you can have the side with lengths $2$, $4$, or $6$. You can move any corner, and then the vector sum of opposite sides changes.

Your first image seems to suggest that the vectors need not be in the same plane, but your second image appears to rely on that. But if this is really a 2-dimensional problem, why do you complicate it with the angle $\psi$?

The problem is in 3D. The second image is an illustration (in 2D) of possible configurations of $\vec{k_1}$, $\vec{k_2}$, $\vec{k_3}$, $\vec{k_4}$ given their possible magnitudes for any $\psi$, which I think are only 3.

But is the quadrilateral planar or not?

I don't see how you could find $|\vec k_1+\vec k_3|$ in terms of $\vec D$ and $\psi$: you can change, for instance, $\vec k_3$ and $\vec k_4$ leaving $\vec D$ and $\psi$ unchanged.

I want it in terms of $\vec{D}$, $\psi$, and the vector magnitudes, which are also given. Then you can't change $\vec{k}_3$ and $\vec{k}_4$ leaving $\vec{D}$ and $\psi$ unchanged. Just updated the question. The quadrilateral is not planar.

From your figure it looks like $\vec k_1$ and $\vec k_2$ lie in the $(xz)$ plane, is it so?

Yes, I chose the coordinate system such that $\vec{k}_1$ and $\vec{k}_2$ lie on the xz plane, with y=0.

Let $\alpha$ be the angle between $\vec k_3$ and $\vec D$ and $\gamma$ the angle between $\vec k_1$ and $-\vec D$, which are known by the cosine rule:
$$
\cos\alpha =\frac{k_3^2+D^2-k_4^2}{2k_3 D} \\
\cos\gamma = \frac{k_1^2+D^2-k_2^2}{2k_1 D}
$$
Then:
$$
\vec k_1=(k_1\sin\gamma,0,-k_1\cos\gamma),
\quad
\vec k_3=(k_3\sin\alpha\cos\psi,k_3\sin\alpha\sin\psi,k_3\cos\alpha)
$$
and a straightforward computation gives:
$$
(\vec k_1+\vec k_3)^2=k_1^2+k_3^2
+2k_1k_3\sin\alpha\sin\gamma\cos\psi
-2k_1k_3\cos\alpha\cos\gamma.
$$

Actually, $\vec{k_1}=(k_1\sin\gamma,0,k_1\cos\gamma)$ and $\vec{k_3}=(k_3\sin\alpha/cos\psi,k_3\sin\alpha\sin\psi,k_3\cos\alpha)$. Please see edit.

You are right: I messed up $\sin$ and $\cos$. But $k_{1z}$ is negative, so the minus should be right. I'll correct in a moment. BTW: you have a wrong sign in the cosine rule, hadn't noticed before.
